# Sort collection in mongodb based on property in Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
    'name':'abc',
    'records': {
        'entries':[
            {
                'date_created':'2020-01-01T00:00:00',
                'some_filed':'value'
            },
            {
                'date_created':'2019-02-03T05:00:00',
                'some_filed':'value'
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    'name':'xyz',
    'records': {
        'entries':[
            {
                'date_created':'2022-03-07T08:00:00',
                'some_filed':'value'
            },
            {
                'date_created':'2022-02-08T10:987:00',
                'some_filed':'value'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have above collection format. I want to sort this based on `date_created` from first record in the array , i.e I want to perform sorting based on `records.entries[0].date_created`.

Also I need to project the `name` and `records.entries[0].date_created` fields.

I tried below queries

```
db['sample_collection'].find({}, {'records.entries.0.date_created':1, 'name':1})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: { firstObject: { $first: "$records.entries.date_created" } }
  },
  {
    $sort: { firstObject: -1 }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jzETA-b60Ky)